# Найти '1' в числе

Tags: c++, математика

Возможно только через математическое выражение определить, есть ли в числе единица?

Например из:

- 100
- 125
- 1175
- 2150

Comment: Смотря какие математические функции разрешено использовать... И вообще - что вам нужно? Написать математическую формулу? Можно. Но если она будет включать, например, сумму или интеграл - это вас устроит? И почему метка - C++? Словом, дайте **точное** ТЗ, без него результат - ХЗ...

Comment: `div | mod` сойдут за математические выражения?

Comment: @slippyk, но без цикла всё равно не получится...

Comment: А в числе `0x9876543210`, например, есть единица или нет?

Comment: Ну... можно так `((x %10)==1)+(((x/10)%10)==1)+(((x/100)%10)==1)+(((x/1000)%10)==1)` для числел от 0 до 9999.

Comment: @Qwertiy *без цикла всё равно не получится* - на спор? :) Стандартная библиотека и никаких циклов :)

Comment: @Qwertiy `bool has_1(int i)
{
    return to_string(i).find('1')!=string::npos;
}` cycle-free :)

Comment: @Harry, а с каких пор `to_string` и `find` относятся к математическим выражениям?)

Comment: @Qwertiy А что такое - *математическое выражение* в языке программирования? :)

Comment: @Harry, то, что в математике можно записать формулой?)

Comment: @Harry, кстати, на спор можно просто захардкодить достаточное количество степеней - чтоб в тип влезло. А то у нас тут не питон.

Comment: @Qwertiy Кстати, да :)

Answer (score 7):

Такой вариант вас не пугает? :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Надеюсь, не ошибся :)

P.P.S. Без символов Кронекера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.P.P.S. Пользуйте

```
bool has_1(int n)
{
    for(;n;n/=10) if (n%10==1) return true; return false;
}
```

и не морочьте голову... :)

Comment: Блин.. Я это прочитать не могу... Что за дельта мелкая? А на мой глянь?

Comment: Я вроде исправил свой вариант :)

Comment: @Qwertiy [Символ Кронекера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: О, точно, был такой. Только я его давно забыл... Так что нагородил вместо него что-то другое)

Comment: @Harry тут есть встроенный LaTeX, или как такая штука делается?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev MathType + вставить картинку :) Картинку можно сделать тут - http://mathurl.com/

Comment: Как ты скобки высокими сделал? И вообще, было бы неплохо формулу записать в alt картинки.

Comment: Могли бы привести название формулы, если оно есть....

Comment: @MrBin Разве что "имени меня" - я их сам придумал :)

Comment: @Harry, буду знать :)

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, как-то так:

```
min(sum i from 0 to infinity of (1 - min(abs(1 - floor(x/10^i) mod 10), 1)), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1. подключаем библиотеки
// 2. считываем строку 
// 3. превращаем строку в число
// 4. число превратить в строку
// 5. найти в строке знак 1

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 10

int main()
{
    char s[256];    // сюда вводим
    char buffer[256];  // а здесь считаем длину

    int x; int err =0;
    bool test_fgets=true;

    do
    {
        // этот блок для того чтобы отлавливать такие "исключения": вводим 33223йцу, а выводит 33223
        do{
            printf("\nВведите целое число :");

            test_fgets=true;
            fgets(s,N,stdin);
            for(int i=0;s[i]!='\n';i++){
                if(test_fgets==true)
                    if(s[i]<'\x30' || s[i]>'\x39'){
                        printf("Ошибка. Повторите ввод!\n"); test_fgets=false;}
            }
        } while(test_fgets!=true);
        // ---

        err=sscanf(s, "%d",&x);
        if (err!=1)
            printf("\n Ошибка ввода. \n ");

    } while (err!=1);

    printf("\n Введено целое число : %d ", x);
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", x); //число превратить в строку
     //ищем в строке знак 1
    int p  = 0; // при появлении знака 1 то датчик p увеличивается
    for (int i =0;i<strlen(buffer);i++)
        if(buffer[i] == '1')
            p++;

     printf("\n в числе символа \"1\" было : %d \n", p);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Главное это вот этот "кусок кода", в этом алгоритме ибо реализаций ввода может быть множество**

```
   //ищем в строке знак 1
    int p  = 0; // при появлении знака 1 то датчик p увеличивается
    for (int i =0;i<strlen(buffer);i++) 
        if(buffer[i] == '1')
            p++;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хоть это си но его легко довести до си++ , в всех `include` убрать .h и всё :3